# controller don't return result without replay.send with fastify platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, fastify

I have login route, that return user:

```
@Post('login')
async login(@Body() user: LoginRequest, @Res() reply): Promise<User> {
    const foundUser = await this.authService.validateUser(user.email, user.password);
    reply.setCookie('t', foundUser._id, { path: '/' });
    // reply.send(foundUser);
    return foundUser;
}
```

My problem is that it is not return nothing (stuck on pending...)), unless I do `reply.send(foundUser);`

I'm using a proxy with allow cors origin:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, new FastifyAdapter());

  // enable cors for static angular site.
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
  };
  app.register(require('fastify-cors'), corsOptions);

  // enable cookie for auth.
  app.register(require('fastify-cookie'));

  // validate types and extra
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidUnknownValues: true }));

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/yantrab/nest-angular/blob/update-nest/server/src/auth/auth.controller.ts) to the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `@Res() reply` from your controller function. As soon as you inject the `response` object, a lot of nest features stop working e.g. Interceptors.

```
@Post('login')
async login(@Body() user: LoginRequest): Promise<User> {
    return this.authService.validateUser(user.email, user.password);
}
```

You could use an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) to set the cookie dynamically instead.